# Cast old string values to datetime with migration in Rails PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I had a couple of date fields in a database table, however they are firstly initiated as string, not datetime. Therefore, I wanted to change those value types to datetype with a migration,

```
class ChangeDateColumnsToDateTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :flight_date_departure, :datetime
    change_column :users, :flight_date, :datetime
    change_column :users, :appointment_date, :datetime
  end
end
```

however it can not cast old string values to datetimes that exists in database currently, saying that 
**PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "flight_date_departure" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone. HINT:  You might need to specify "USING flight_date_departure::timestamp without time zone".** We've done it without problem in a SQLite database, however there is this problem for PostgreSQL. How can I modify my migration so that I do not lose old values and properly convert them to datetime?

Comment: **workaround:** Add new `datatime` column, write a `rake task` to copy string values to datatime column (probably you need to use `to_datetime` to convert string to datetime), drop old string column, & you may need to rename your datetime column to `flight_date_departure`

Answer (score 9):

I've tried the way bellow and it worked like a charm:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'timestamp USING CAST(column_name AS timestamp)'
```

Comment: This worked for me with postgres on Rails 5.2, thanks!

Comment: This works well for Rails 6.1, not Rehan solution

Answer (score 7):

try like this:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'datetime USING CAST(column_name AS datetime)'
```

Comment: does not work for me `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "datetime" does not exist`

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a `datetime` data type but `timestamp` or `date`. See [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

here is my working code

```
class AddSrCreateDateToCart < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :carts, :sr_create_date, :datetime
    change_column :carts, :sr_create_date, 'datetime USING CAST(sr_create_date AS timestamp)'
  end
end
```

postgres is now downloading the data

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make this a reversible migration.

```
def up
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'timestamp USING CAST(column_name AS timestamp)'
end

def down
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, 'date USING CAST(column_name AS date)'
end
```